# Widget repeaters in gtk3 using python and glade

Tags: python, glade, gtk3

I am trying to develop applications for gtk3 using python. I have designed the UI using glade. I want to know if there is any way of using widget arrays, in which each widget of similar type would have the same name, but with a different index. It would help in reducing code to a great extent.

In my application, I have 10 label widgets which display different data, based on an array of data. Now I have to call the `gbuilder.get_object()` method every time I need to get the desired object. If I were able to use widget arrays, it would really help in reducing the code redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have named the widgets in glade like this:

- `<widget_name>_1`
- `<widget_name>_2`
- ...
- `<widget_name>_n`

It would be easy to create such a list of widgets in your application like this:

```
widget_list = [builder.get_object('<widget_name>_{0}'.format(i))
               for i in range(1, n+1)]
```

To get, for example, item 7, all you need is index the list (note that indexes start with 0):

```
widget_list[6]
```

The purpose of `{0}` is generate the names of the widgets:

```
>> ['<widget_name>_{0}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 4)
['<widget_name>_1', '<widget_name>_2', '<widget_name>_3']
```

For more information about how to use `format`, please have a look at the [format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: and how do i use the data from <widget_name>_7 from the list.
also, what is the purpose of the {0} ?

Comment: @GauravSood I've edited my answer to add the information you asked in the comment.

Comment: i got the method. just one question. i have 10 button, which correspond to the same method upon click. i have used a list. there is usage of dictionary for the various signals emitted. how do i add the list of buttons to the dict and should i use the same signal for all the buttons? also, in the method, how am i going to check which button was clicked?
the dict is of this format:
    <code>dic={'on_<widget name>_clicked':method, 
           'on_<widget name>_clicked':method1} 
      builder.connect_signals(dic) 
    <code>

Comment: Please for the benefit of other people that might have the same problem in the future, don't use comments to ask new questions.